# Run a program within a batch file

Tags: oracle, batch-file

I need to make a batch file which will execute a series of commands within a program. I need it to connect to an oracle database and then initiate a pull.

Here is by current file:

```
sqlplus [username]/[pass]@[host]:[port]/[service]
set feedback off
set term off
set linesize 32000
set pagesize 0
set trimspool on
set underline off
set heading on
set newpage none
spool C:\1.csv CREATE
[Query Goes here]
```

I run the script, but it doesn't execute anything except the first line. It connects okay, but waits for me to quit sqlplus to execute the rest of the script. Is there a way to fix this? If possible I would like to avoid using multiple files.

Comment: put your commands in a text file, and call it like `sqlplus [username]/[pass]@[host]:[port]/[service] @/path/to/sqlplus_command_file.txt`. (I think!). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone comes across this question looking for a *nix based solution, it'd be something like this:

```
sqlplus -s <username>/password <<EOF
set feedback off
set term off
set linesize 32000
set pagesize 0
set trimspool on
set underline off
set heading on
set newpage none
spool C:\1.csv CREATE
 EOF
```

The subsequent commands are sent to SQLPLUS until it encounters EOF, then SQLPLUS will close.

But I'm not sure how to do the equivalent on Windows.

Comment: @BrianFurtado did this work on Windows? Or did you have to modify anything?